# Add ID To Row And Update Reply Rows With Same ID?

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

Hope you are all well. I have made an email reporting tool and I am really struggling with this. Each row has an ID number (starting from 1 and on row 2 in Column G). When a reply comes in I need the reply to have its original ID. Tried using  entryid but this value changes when a reply email comes back so its not very good.

Here is my code bellow;

```
Option Explicit
Const fPath As String = "C:\Users\neo_s_000\Desktop\Emails\" 'The path to save the messages
Const sfName As String = "C:\Users\neo_s_000\Desktop\Message Log.xlsx"

Sub Download_Outlook_Mail_To_Excel()
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim xlBook As Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim olItem As Object
    If FileExists(sfName) Then
        Set xlBook = Workbooks.Open(sfName)
        Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
    Else
        Set xlBook = Workbooks.Add
        Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
        With xlSheet
            .Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
            .Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
            .Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
            '.Cells(1, 4) = "Size"
            .Cells(1, 5) = "EmailID"
            .Cells(1, 6) = "Body"
            .Cells(1, 7) = "ID"
        End With
        xlBook.SaveAs sfName
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    With xlSheet
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
        '.Cells(1, 4) = "Size"
        .Cells(1, 5) = "EmailID"
        .Cells(1, 6) = "Body"
        .Cells(1, 7) = "ID"
        CreateFolders fPath
        Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        olNS.Logon
        Set olFolder = olNS.PickFolder
        For Each olItem In olFolder.Items
            NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If olItem.Class = 43 Then
                .Cells(NextRow, 1) = olItem.Sender
                .Cells(NextRow, 2) = olItem.Subject
                .Cells(NextRow, 3) = olItem.SentOn
                '.Cells(NextRow, 4) =
                .Cells(NextRow, 5) = SaveMessage(olItem)
                .Cells(NextRow, 6) = olItem.Body
            End If
        Next olItem
        MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"
    End With
    xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
lbl_Exit:
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Function SaveMessage(olItem As Object) As String
Dim Fname As String
    Fname = Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd") & Chr(32) & _
            Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "HH.MM") & Chr(32) & olItem.sendername & " - " & olItem.Subject
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(41), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(40), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(34), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(42), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(47), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(60), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(62), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(63), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(124), "-")
    SaveMessage = SaveUnique(olItem, fPath, Fname)
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function

Private Function SaveUnique(oItem As Object, _
                            strPath As String, _
                            strFileName As String) As String

Dim lngF As Long
Dim lngName As Long
    lngF = 1
    lngName = Len(strFileName)
    Do While FileExists(strPath & strFileName & ".msg") = True
        strFileName = Left(strFileName, lngName) & "(" & lngF & ")"
        lngF = lngF + 1
    Loop
    oItem.SaveAs strPath & strFileName & ".msg"
    SaveUnique = strPath & strFileName & ".msg"
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function

Private Sub CreateFolders(strPath As String)
Dim strTempPath As String
Dim iPath As Long
Dim vPath As Variant
    vPath = Split(strPath, "\")
    strPath = vPath(0) & "\"
    For iPath = 1 To UBound(vPath)
        strPath = strPath & vPath(iPath) & "\"
        If Not FolderExists(strPath) Then MkDir strPath
    Next iPath
End Sub

Private Function FolderExists(ByVal PathName As String) As Boolean
   Dim nAttr As Long
   On Error GoTo NoFolder
   nAttr = GetAttr(PathName)
   If (nAttr And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
      FolderExists = True
   End If
NoFolder:
End Function

Private Function FileExists(filespec) As Boolean
Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(filespec) Then
        FileExists = True
    Else
        FileExists = False
    End If
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to have all replies to an email be able to tie back to the ID you assigned the original email. 

If that's what you want, you can do so by looking at the [RootItem(s)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866457.aspx) of the [Conversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862527.aspx) object, which you can obtain from a mail item using [GetConversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869870.aspx).

Comment: Exactly. That I what I want to do. Sorry if I made it sound a tad confusing.

Comment: The above all seems to be related to Outlook. Can I write that code in Excel? I am not very good in all honesty at understanding what this is showing.

Comment: Everything you're doing is related to outlook ;)  Reading over your code, you are using late binding. [Add a reference to the outlook library in your project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865816.aspx) so you can use early binding.

Comment: Yes it is but what I mean is I dont have to add any of the code to outlook. This is all written in Excel.

Comment: Bere with me here. I am quite a novice at this stuff haha. But what you said at the start is exactly what I need to do. Its just understanding how to do it that is causing me the issues.

Comment: Also I havent actually added any ID to any emails. The ID exists on a Spreadsheet.

Comment: It's all written in **VBA**.  You are writing it in the Excel VBA IDE.  Since VBA is more of an add-in IDE, it has some special functions - basically whatever program you launch it from it makes the default namespace.  So if you want to access other namespaces (class libraries) you add a reference.  The above link explains how to add the reference and to change from late binding to early binding.  I'm leaving work now, but read through that link and if you get stuck I'll see if I can help more tomorrow.

Comment: Ok set the reference. Now I will have to amend my code to early binding? Kinda unsure what to do now :(

Comment: You don't have to - you can continue using late binding as you are, but I wouldn't recommend it.  I can't really get into more detail right this minute though. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying but really am unsure how to implement this into my code and how Ito will generate a number on my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, sorry it took so long to get an answer to you. I'll try to give you the run down on what I was saying in comments.

---

**Early vs. Late binding**
In [OOP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd460654.aspx) all of the objects we interact with have a [Type (aka Class)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd460654.aspx#Classes).
We use these objects by accessing the members associated with them, which is defined by their type. 
In order to access these members, the runtime environment needs to know what the type is.

We can tell the runtime environment what the type is before we execute the code (so at compile-time), this is called Early Binding.  Alternatively, we can let the RTE figure it out while executing (so during run-time) which is called Late Binding.

Defining a type at compile-time is done by declaring the object as the intended type.  E.g.:

```
Dim xlApp as Excel.Application
```

Defining it at run-time is done by declaring the object as a base type and then casting it to another type which inherits the base type.  Most commonly the base type of `Object` is used, as all types are derived from the `Object` type.  (or `Variant` is commonly seen in VBA as it can represent any data-type) .  E.g.:

```
Dim xlApp as Object
```

The major advantage to you (the programmer) of using early binding is Intellisense, but there are many advantages to using early binding such as program optimization, debugging, error trapping, etc.

You can read more about these concepts [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx), but that's the jist of it.

---

**Type libraries**

In order to declare an object as the type we want, we need to ensure that type is available to the IDE.  Types are contained in libraries (commonly .DLL files) and we can add references to these libraries to use the types that are defined in them.   In VBA we do this by "adding a reference", which is available from the `Tools` menu.

---

All of this is explained in the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865816.aspx) I linked to yesterday.

---

**Implementing Early Binding:**

To use early binding, set the reference as described in the link above, and then change your variable declarations to callout the appropriate type from the `Outlook` namespace like so:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim xlBook As Workbook  'This is the same as Excel.Workbook... Excel is the default namespace and a reference is automatically included in your VBA project when you enter VBA from Excel (e.g. using AL+F11 or macro-recorder)
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet  'Same as Excel.Worksheet...
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim olItem As Object  'Here we have to use late binding because the return from Folder.Items collection can contain objects of multiple types (e.g. MailItem, MeetingItem, AppointmentItem, etc.)
```

---

**Implementing an ID field:**

As far as populating an ID field, you could probably get what you want using the [Conversation.ConversationID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff869792.aspx) property.

E.g.

```
For Each olItem In olFolder.Items
    NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If olItem.Class = 43 Then
        .Cells(NextRow, 1) = olItem.Sender
        .Cells(NextRow, 2) = olItem.Subject
        .Cells(NextRow, 3) = olItem.SentOn
        '.Cells(NextRow, 4) =
        .Cells(NextRow, 5) = SaveMessage(olItem)
        .Cells(NextRow, 6) = olItem.Body

        Dim Convo as Outlook.Conversation
        Set Convo = olItem.GetConversation()
        .Cells(NextRow, 7) = convo.conversationID
    End If
Next olItem
```

Comment: Wow thanks CBRF23 dude. That now makes much more sense. I kinda worked out the conversation ID part. The Early Binding I had no idea on. This should make troubleshooting a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply also. Was ill V_V not been ill in years and I was bed ridden for a few days.